# read a file line by line and assign the values to variable as comma separated

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following a.txt file:

```
abc,
def,
ghi
```

I want to read it line-by-line, and store in a varibale as  comma seperated values

```
var1=abc,def,ghi
```

i am new to shell script pls help

My try:

```
name="file.txt"
while IFS=read -r line
do
    names=`echo $line`
done < "name"
```

it is displaying only value ghi to varibale

Comment: Thanks, pls share me script. I am very new to shell

Comment: Please show your attempt. Even if you're a beginner, you're expected to learn the basics yourself.

Comment: My try:

name="file.txt" while IFS=read -r line do names=echo $line done < "name"

Comment: it is displaying only value ghi to varibale

Comment: `names="$names,$line"`

Comment: `var1=$(tr -d \\n < a.txt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not concatenating, you're replacing the `names` variable each time through the loop.

There's no need to use `echo` when assigning the variable.

```
name="file.txt"
names=
while IFS=read -r line
do
    names="$names$line"
done < "name"
```

Comment: it will store a abcdefghi

is it possible with while loop IFS ?

Comment: Why? The file  you show has `,` at the end of each line, my answer doesn't remove them.

Comment: with above changes i am getting abc,,def,,ghi

Comment: it has removed first comma

Comment: Make up your mind. Does the file already have commas in it or not?

Comment: yes it is already comma like below

abc,
def,
ghi

no comma for last line

Comment: sorry i am not able comment line by line. 

abc, - first line
def, - second line
ghi - third line

Comment: Then my first answer should have worked. I removed the added comma here.

Comment: Thanks u so much it worked as expected :)